# Where should we make api calls in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, architecture, payment-gateway

I am working on a Rails application and I have to integrate some payment gateways in it. 
Now One of the functionality of these gateways is 3Dsecure payments.
The flow of these payments is something like this.

1. user enters his billing address details etc in a form.
2. server sends a secure payment request to Payment Gateway(PG) server
3. PG returns a special link, where user needs to be redirected.
4. User goes to that link, enters card info and/or enter secure Bank code.
5. PG's server sends user back to our server on to the provided return url with some credentials.
6. our server verifies if the payment was successful by doing another api calls
7. on success we save a row in database.

Now I am very confused about how to implement this behaviour in rails.

- If I am doing api calls in the model I cannot redirect the user from there.
- If I am doing api calls in the controller I am unable to send errors to the form incase any api call throws error.
- I need to save the payment details only on the callback but how do I get access to the submitted form data in my callback function.
- Where should I implement my callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Write a PORO wrapper class and shove it into the `lib` folder. That way you can re-use it anywhere you need.

Another option would be to make a non AR "model" that handles the data and then have a controller to do the redirects

Comment: can you point me to any implementation or tutorial of what you are saying

Comment: @AsimAdnan Take a look: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty and http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/working-with-external-apis. Google for the other results

Comment: how can I do redirects in PORO?

Comment: @AsimAdnan You will probably have to write a controller to handle the payments and do all the redirects. Or pass controller (`self`) to the PORO. Then you can call methods on it to do redirects